# MS Azure Data Factory ADF Copy Activity from BLOB to Azure Postgres Gen5 8 cores fails with connection closed by host error

Tags: azure, copy, connection, npgsql, socketexception

I am using ADF copy acivity to copy files on azure blob to azure postgres.. im doing recursive copy i.e. there are multiple files withing the folder.. thats fine.. size of 5 files which i have to copy is total around 6 gb. activity fails after 30-60 min of run. used write batch size from 100- 500 but still fails. 
used 4 or 8 orauto DIUS, similarly tried used 1,2,4,8 or auto parallel connections to postgres.normally it seems it uses 1 per source file. azure postgres server has 8 cores and temp buffer size is 8192 kb. max allowed is 16000 something kb. even tried using that but 2 errors which i have been constantly getting. ms support team suggested to use retry option. still awaiting response from there pg team if i get something but below r the errors.

Answer: {
'errorCode': '2200',
'message': ''Type=Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Message=Exception while reading from stream,Source=Npgsql,''Type=System.IO.IOException,Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,Source=System,'',
'failureType': 'UserError',
'target': 'csv to pg staging data migration',
'details': []
}

or

Operation on target csv to pg staging data migration failed: 'Type=Npgsql.NpgsqlException,Message=Exception while flushing stream,Source=Npgsql,''Type=System.IO.IOException,Message=Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,Source=System

Comment: That error indicates that the PostgreSQL server closed the connection for some reasons. You should have access to the logs where some message should shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need some more details. Azure postgres logs (I even changed server property log_error_verbosity to Verbose) simply give a similar error message which I have pasted above. Do you know which other server property I need to change to see the detailed logs ? Any why postgres is closing connection.. I see metyrics.. max memory utilization is < 60%, cpu < 20 %.. error seems to be related to IO .. ax IO percent is 60..

Comment: Any chance you can repro this on a regular PostgreSQL on a dev machine?

Comment: No, as I am using ADF copy act from Blobs to Azure Pg. I am waiting for MS support PG team response.Issue is straightforward. connection is being killed. who kills it and why ? Is ADF not capable to handling such large volume loads. It works fine for say 20 million records in multiple csv files in source around 10 GB, but fails for anything more. I use max allowed DIUs & parallel copies. I tried enabling logs,that gave little more detail saying some front end errors.. to me which meant the same thing that conn is closed. I removed SSL & vnet as well. adf in europe. blob & pg in other region

Comment: MS support confirmed its a known issue to product engineers, ADF copy activity may give this issue when data size is too big or takes long time to copy. They plan to come up with a fix as soon as sometime early next month. Issue is due to the underlying drive Npgsql they use..... sad part is in ms docs they say default write batch is 10000.. and for this issue, they have suggested to try with a smaller batch size may be 10 to make it work. I tried. it works randomly. for same data in source and sink sometimes 1000 batch size works, sometimes even 100 fails. will try with 10, but may take weeks

Comment: If this is an issue in Npgsql, could you please ask MS support to get in touch with me so we can discuss possible fixes?

Comment: Issue is with MS AZure copy activity only. If we see this error, only option is to hit and trial with different settings and sometime it will work with some settings, and sometimes not with same setting, need to raise issue with ms support and they will fix the issues in 5-7 days.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue recently and contacted our microsoft rep who got back to me with the following update on 2020-01-16:

> “This is another issue we found in the driver, we just finished our
>   deployment yesterday to fix this issue by upgrading driver version.
>   Now customer can have up to 32767 columns data in one batch size(which
>   is the limitation in PostgreSQL, we can’t exceed that).
>
> Please let customer make sure that (Write batch size* column size)<
>   32767  as I mentioned, otherwise they will face the limitation. “

"Column size" refers to the count of columns in the table.  The "area" (row write batch size * column count) cannot be greater than 32,767.

I was able to change my ADF write batch size on copy activity to a dynamic formula to ensure optimum batch sizes per table with the following:

```
@div(32766,length(pipeline().parameters.config)
```

`pipeline().parameters.config` refers to an array containing information about columns for the table.  the length of the array = number of columns for table.

hope this helps!  I was able to populate the database (albeit slowly) via ADF... would much prefer a COPY based method for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I escalated big time as it was impacting our project timelines,  and got the same response from MS support. They fixed the same within a couple of days. I am sorry to post a little late as got busy with work, but yes, it was an issue with their driver. They deployed the fix, and after that since then, ADF works smooth. They initially recommened me to use a small batch size like 100 or 10, but after fix, I was even able to use 2000, and copy speed was very fast. @dabears318 .. your solution to use write batch size dynamically is great. Appreciate and Thanks.

Comment: Thanks dabears318, I was trying to dynamically provide write batch size as you recommended but unable to understand how to pass , and actually we should not pass but it should be automatically able to fetch col info from target table i.e. no. of cols.. can you please explain how your code is getting value for config parameter.

Comment: Hi Harsh, I am doing a SQL server source to PostGres target copy where I run a "Lookup" ADF function that utilizes an introspective SQL query on source table server which returns data about the table (a list of columns, their types, are they primary keys etc.) which I then feed into the copy script as a JSON object.  I am able to get the length (count of columns) from this.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Hi @HarshKishore, please consider accepting this as answer - while not perfect I believe this correctly summarizes the issue and resolves with a suggestion for improved performance.

Comment: @HarshKishore Is this still an issue with ADF? I'm having the same issue and it sounds like the same problem.

Comment: This worked for me! I set Write batch size to `(32767 / ColumnCount) - 50`. The `-50` was just to add some padding.